# What is IEntity in this code for a generic repository pattern?

Tags: generics, design-patterns, interface, repository-pattern

I have seen this code in a few places.  What is IEntity doing in the code below?  I know that IEntity is not an interface, even though it's prefixed with "I".  Additionally, I understand it may be acting as an ID for the entities returned from the repository.  When would this ID be set? I'm looking for a good explination of the interface use of IEntity and how it relates to "T".

Code from: http://blog.falafel.com/implement-step-step-generic-repository-pattern-c/

```
public class IEntity
{
    public string Id; 
}

public interface IRepository<T> where T: IEntity
{

    IEnumerable<T> List { get; }
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    T FindById(int Id);

}
```

Comment: It is serving as a constraint on T. Only classes that are derived from IEntity can be used to create a repository via the generic class.  If you try and create a repository with a class not derived from IEntity you will receive a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  Any idea why it's acting as a constraint?

Comment: To make sure the class has everything the repository needs.

Answer (score 3):

It's a generic type parameter constraint to define what type of entities can handle a repository.

That is, `TEntity` is `IEntity` or any derived class, but at least `TEntity` references will gain compile-time access to `IEntity` members. This is a **huge improvement** since you don't need to perform run-time type checks prior to casting a reference because you don't need a cast anymore.

For example, `Add(TEntity)` without generics would look as `Add(Entity)` which would force the runtime to perform an *upcast* (f.e. `Add(new DerivedEntity())` which upcasts `DerivedEntity` to `Entity`).

When using generics, an `IRepository<DerivedEntity>` will compile `Add` as `Add(DerivedEntity)`, so, *where's the cast right now when adding an entity of type `DerivedEntity`?* ;)

> When would this ID be set?

Usually the repository implementation should set the `TEntity.Id`:

```
public void Add(TEntity entity)
{
    // "entity" reference can access TEntity.Id because TEntity is
    // at least IEntity
    entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is this the database primary key?  For example if I have an identity field on my database table (called Id) can I just skip the call in the Add(TEntity entity) and set it on the Get method?

Comment: @TravisK In my case I try to avoid using *identity fields* but I go with the guidcomb strategy which is in summary generating the identifiers in your application layer rather than in the database...BTW yes, you can skip setting the whole `Id` since you're using an *identity*, and all objects returned by *gets* should go with the whole `Id` already set